# how to target codebehind method using __DoPostBack without hidden control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to call a server side method using __DoPostBack, but i don't want a hidden ASP runat server control in my page. Is it possible to call a server side method by its name and not by the name of the control that triggers it?

The problem is, I have an asp button on my aspx page with onclick="ExportButton_Click", and when the button is clicked, it calls the ExportButton_Click codebehind (server side) method.  My problem is, I want to get rid of the asp button, because I am trying to create a button dynamically, which when clicked, will do the same thing.  Right now, my dynamically created button is calling the doPostBack javascript function which targets the asp Button which triggers ExportButton_Click.  So... is it possible to call the ExportButton_Click codebehind method with __doPostBack, without having an asp button?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the event target argument in to the `__DoPostBack('myEvent')` method, like that.

Then in your code-behind `Page_Load()`, have somewhere code like this:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == "myEvent")
{
    //call your button click function, and pass the button to it (can pass null as the EventArgs)
    Button1_Click(Button1, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These two methods are your server-side friends:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference
this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
```

They can be used to generate javascript to link to your server side events.